# Boundary of image of set is contained in image of boundary of set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ holomorphic. Prove that $\partial f(B(0,1))\subset f(C(0,1))$.

I know that $f(\overline{B(0,1)})$ is compact, but I don't know how to proceed..

Comment: Im assuming that $B$ is the open ball but what is $C$? It can't be closed ball. If it is, it must be inclusion, and not equality. Right?

Comment: @PauloMourao $C(0,1)=\{z\in\mathbf{C}\mid|z|=1 \}$, the unit circle

Comment: You should restate the conclusion, as $=$ need not hold.

Answer (score 1):

It is $\partial f(\mathbb{D})\subset f(\partial\mathbb{D})$. You can easily see this using the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). I feel that in order to prove the reverse inclusion you need that $f$ is also one-to-one, but I'm not absolutely sure.

($\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disk)

Comment: Can you elaborate please??

Comment: see @matematleta 's answer, it contains the details of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Remark: if $f$ is not constant, and $z\in U\subseteq B$, then $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb C$ whenever $U$ is open in $\bar B$.

Let $w\in \partial f(B)$. By compactness, there is a sequence $(w_n)\subseteq f(B)$ such that $w_n\to w,$ so there is a sequence $(z_n)\subseteq B$ such that $f(z_n)=w_n.$ Again, by compactness, there is a subsequence of $(z_n)$, which we still call $(z_n)$ for convenience, such that $z_n\to z\in \bar B.$ Continuity of $f$ implies that $f(z)=w$. Now, if $z\notin \partial B$, then by the remark, $w\notin \partial f(B)$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $z\in \partial B$, which implies that $\partial f(B)\subseteq f(\partial B).$

Answer (score 1):

To see $=$ need not hold, let $f(z)=z(1-z).$ Then $f(0)=0.$ By the open mapping theorem, $0$ is an interior point of $f(\mathbb D).$ Thus $0\notin \partial [f(\mathbb D)].$ But $f(1)=0$ as well, so $0\in f(\partial \mathbb D) \setminus \partial [f(\mathbb D)].$

Comment: It's a great exercise to draw the image of the unit circle and then of the interior and exterior of the unit disc to see what happens (0 interior to the image of the interior of the disc but boundary for the image of the exterior of the disc, while $-2$ the other way); the reason of course is that the images of the interior and exterior of the unit disc are not disjoint!

Comment: @zhw. thanks ! I only need the inclusion $\subset$ however.